# Удаление роли с сервера, дискорд

Tags: python, discord.py

Я хочу удалить роль с сервера, с помощью бота, как это можно сделать?

Comment: @Man4 если бы я нашел это в гугле, я бы не писал сюда. Не можете помочь - не засоряйте чат вопроса.

Comment: @Man4, данный комментарий противоречит политике сайта - не рекомендуется посылать в Google вместо ответа. Можете дать ответ, приведя параллельно ссылку. Или предложить закрыть вопрос, если ответ есть на этом сайте.

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал await role.delete() и все получилось:

```
role=discord.utils.get(mes.message.guild.roles, name=name)
await role.delete()
```